# ractive : how to call super () inside a child class?

Tags: ractivejs

That is going to be a super easy question. I have the following code :

```
var component = ractive.extend ({
...
onrender : function (){...}
...
})

var view = component.extend({
...
onrender : function (){...}
})
```

The `onrender` in `view` is executed and shadows the `onrender` in `component`. Is there a way to call the `onrender` in `component` from the `view` context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `this._super` inside the overriding method to refer to the underlying function:

```
onrender: function(){
    this._super();
    // ...
}
```

It's on [this page](http://docs.ractivejs.org/edge/ractive-extend) in the docs (though example is with the old lifecycle methods).